# How to select multiple songs that are/were made by several artists in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to select songs that created by several artists.

These are my tables:

```
Artist
-----------------------------
(id,nickName)

Song
-----------------------------
(id,name,photoPath)
```

`Artist`s and `Song`s have a many to many relationship

I can do this with this way:

```
var songs = ctx.song
    .Where(s =>  s.artist.Any(a => a.nickName == "jack") && s.artist.Any(a => a.nickName == "sara"))
    .ToList()
```

However I think not best way to selects songs with 3 or more artists in EF. How can i write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check against a collection of artists like this:

```
var artists = new [] { "jack", "sara", "bob" };

var songs = ctx.song
    .Where(s => artists
        .All(a => s.artist
            .Any(x => x.nickname == a)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: i think you should remove the all! from the above.. it will still work and be better, the All is not need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `s.artist` is the list of `Artist`-objects. If I am right and if you only need the songs that have multiple artists, you could use the `Count` property for that:

```
var songs = ctx.song.Where(s => s.artist.Count > 1).ToList();
```